# How to redirect in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that acts as a dashboard and displays links for different 
 React applications. Users can select the application by clicking a button.
In short I need to redirect to a different URL based on user selection.

In the sample code below, trying to redirect to a URL using withRouter. However its giving the below error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I am using React 15.6.1.

## index.js

```
render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Home />
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

## home.js

```
class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.loadApp1 = this.loadApp1.bind(this);
    }

    loadApp1() {
        this.props.route.push('/app1');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <button onClick={this.loadApp1}>App1</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Did it help?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Link to do this:

```
import { Link } from react-router-dom;
```

Then,

```
<button><Link to="/app1">App1</Link></button>
```

Will route to the App1 route.

For an external site, you could do this:

```
   loadApp1() {
        window.location = "example.com";
    }
```

Comment: I need to route to an external app outside this react app

Comment: I have updated the answer to include external pages.

Comment: Thanks @Dream_Cap  it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your `loadApp1` should be

```
 loadApp1() {
    this.props.history.push('/app1');
}
```